# How to solve variable not initialize in flutter State?

Tags: flutter

I am using floor to develop app with sqlite db.

But when I start to initialize the database object I got this error:

```
Variable database has not been initialized.
```

This is my code:

```
class _DoctorScreenPageState extends State<DoctorScreenPage> {
  late AppDatabase database;
  List<Doctor> doctors = [];
  late StreamSubscription subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    $FloorAppDatabase
        .databaseBuilder('database.db')
        .build()
        .then((value) async {
      database = value;
      
    });
    
  }
}
```

Comment: seems it is future, you can use `FutureBuilder` in this case, or you can make nullable data and check while using it. `AppDatabase? database `, also you may need to use `setState` in that case being `future`.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do this by showing me a code sample.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did what you told me and everything works fine.

Comment: Glad to help you out.